# Using Epilog and Graphics to plot points and lines

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm attempting to put a point onto my Plot but need help with the point sizing and using the Graphics function. I'm not sure I'm going about this correctly, but I have been able to produce the lines that I'm looking for using the Line function inside the epilog option. I'm confused about how Mathematica handles marking up Plots. I also want to call out my intersection of the two lines and need help.

Here is what I'm looking for:

- Callout point of intersection with the (x,y) value at that point.
- Adjust the size of the point of intersection
- Add arrows to indicate the direction of the slope

I need clarification about how Mathematica combines its graphics rendering with its plots. I can use Line to place a line inside my Plot but then using Graphics to add other stuff causes errors. What is the proper way to understand how these are rendered so I can add markup to my Plots?

Here is the code with errors:

```
Plot[{2.13 + 0.7 (-7.4 + x), 2.13 + 0.9 (-8.9 + x)}, {x, 6, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {
    {Red, Line[{{14.15, 0}, {14.15, 6.855}}]}, 
    {Red, Line[{{6, 6.855}, {14.15, 6.855}}]}, 
    {Blue, Graphics[PointSize[0.1], Point[{14.15, 6.855}]]}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> "Supply & Demand", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bushels", "Price"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}]
```

[image]

Here is the working Code:

```
Plot[{2.13 + 0.7 (-7.4 + x), 2.13 + 0.9 (-8.9 + x)},{x, 6, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {
    {Red, Line[{{14.15, 0}, {14.15, 6.855}}]}, 
    {Red, Line[{{6, 6.855}, {14.15, 6.855}}]},
    {Blue,Point[{14.15,6.855}]}}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> "Supply & Demand", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bushels", "Price"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}]
```

Comment: I'm sorry there is an error in my slope calculation for demand. Please don't judge me!

Comment: Have the labels been interchanged for "supply" and "demand"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Plot[{2.13 + 0.7 (-7.4 + x), 2.13 + 0.9 (-8.9 + x)}, {x, 6, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> "Supply & Demand", 
   AxesLabel -> {"Bushels", "Price"}, 
   PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}],
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{{14.15, 0}, {14.15, 6.855}}],  
    Line[{{6, 6.855}, {14.15, 6.855}}], Blue, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[{14.15, 6.855}]}]
  }]
```

[image]

You can also do it with the Epilog as follows:

```
Plot[{2.13 + 0.7 (-7.4 + x), 2.13 + 0.9 (-8.9 + x)}, {x, 6, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, Line[{{14.15, 0}, {14.15, 6.855}}]}, {Red, 
    Line[{{6, 6.855}, {14.15, 6.855}}]},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.05], Point[{14.15, 6.855}]}
   }, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> "Supply & Demand", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bushels", "Price"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}]
```

Have fun!

Comment: Ah, so I'm placing my Graphics on top of my plot? In the first example you gave. Then how do I do the arrows? How do I place a coordinate point callout?

Comment: You can combine everything wrapping the graphics functions by the `Show`.  Have a look at `Arrow`. You use it like `Line`.  For the coordinates of the point, try either `Callout` or `Text`. Have a look at all these functions in the documentation. They are easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

To make the faulty version  work and still use `Epilog`, replace `Graphics[...]` with `First@Graphics[...]`. This is to remove the `Head` `Graphics` and makes `Epilog` happy

```
Plot[{2.13 + 0.7 (-7.4 + x), 2.13 + 0.9 (-8.9 + x)}, {x, 6, 20},
 Epilog -> {
   {Red, Line[{{14.15, 0}, {14.15, 6.855}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{6, 6.855}, {14.15, 6.855}}]},
   {First@Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.03], Point[{14.15, 6.855}]}]}},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> "Supply & Demand", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bushels", "Price"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When this one is compiled it doesn't produce an error but it still doesn't create the point.

Comment: @Ziggy  There was no mention in the question about compile. I do not know anything about Compile and if it even supports plotting. May be post separate question on Compile not working with Plots? I was just answering your question on how to make Epilog accept Graphics.

Comment: I'm talking about compiled as in when you hit shift + enter to have Mathematica run the code. This code you wrote compiles without errors inside the Mathematica notebook but still doesn't produce a blue dot.

Comment: @Ziggy oh I thought you meant Compile command. The correct term to use is `Evaluate` and not `Compile` in Mathematica to mean what you meant as the two terms mean something different. As for the blue point, I was just using your code. You need to move the color inside the Graphics. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thank you!